# How to get text without html tags

Tags: php, html, css, string

I have a Database table to save news. the news field type is TEXT (I save the news with its styles inline).
Now when I show the news on the site it shows with all the styles and that is great but my problem is:
I want to make last 10 news table on mainpage will show the title and PART OF NEWS i use a php code to get some letters from my returned news value from the database:

```
$str1 = $cat_news[$i]['news'];
$str1 = wordwrap($str1, 100);
$str1 = explode("\n", $str1);
```

when I echo the $str[1]; it shows me the styles like this:

```
letter-spacing: normal; orphans: auto; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none;
```

I want to show the text without any style just some letters from the text followed by ...

Comment: This could help you


[How can one parse HTML/XML and extract information from it?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: I'm using this [inputfilter](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2189-PHP-Filter-out-unwanted-PHP-Javascript-HTML-tags-.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function in PHP called [`strip_tags`](https://www.php.net/strip_tags).
You can use it like this:

```
$str1 = $cat_news[$i]['news'];
$str1 = strip_tags($str1);
$str1 = wordwrap($str1, 100);
$str1 = explode("\n", $str1);
```

This should get rid of all HTML formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [strip_tags()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php), but beware it can remove more than you think if the HTML is badly formatted etc. It doesn't do proper check on the formatting etc. It might also be possible to use [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), but it really depends on how proper and complete the text and formatting is.